# I need a listview with custom designed toggle button which can be selected only one at a time

Tags: android, listview, togglebutton

The code below code can be select multiple choice. I only need to select one with a custom toggle button design.

I need to select one option and get the id of the selected toggle button. I searched on the internet for custom listview with single selection toggle button but I didn't find anything useful.

I simply need to add 5 toggle buttons dynamically - when I select one the others should be deselected.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int startminute;
    int endminute;

    Date date;
    ToggleButton togg;
    ListView lv;
    String[] days = {"SUNDAY", "MONDAY", "TUESDAY", "WEDNESDAY", "THURSDAY",
            "FRIDAY", "SATURDAY"};
    boolean[] onOff = new boolean[]{false, false, false, false, false, false,
            false};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            onOff = savedInstanceState.getBooleanArray("status");
        }
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        lv.setAdapter(new MyAdapter());
        lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                    int position, long arg3) {



            }
        });

    }

    public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        public int getCount() {
            return days.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {

            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return days.length;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                            ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = null;
            TextView arryText;

            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }
            arryText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.inflateText);
            togg = (ToggleButton) v.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
            v.setTag(new ViewHolder(arryText, togg));

            togg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (onOff[position]) {
                        togg.setChecked(false);
                        onOff[position] = false;

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "is off",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {

                        onOff[position] = true;
                        togg.setChecked(true);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "is on",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                }
            });

            arryText.setText(days[position]);
            togg.setChecked(onOff[position]);



            return v;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBooleanArray("status", onOff);
    }
}
```

Comment: think of using databinding to do this

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a boolean array you can use an integer that indicates the position of the selected item.

when loading the value in the toggleButton it would be like this:

```
togg.setChecked(selectedDay == position);
```

And the item click listener:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    //Store selected position
    selectedDay = position;

    //Reload all items
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```